build.gradle file is showing null in small paranthesis and nothing happens when I click on "Sync All Gradle Projects"
I installed IntelliJ Idea on my Raspberry Pi 5 using Pi-Apps. build.gradle file is showing null in small parenthesis and nothing happens when I click on "Sync All Gradle Projects". I reinstalled IntelliJ but still facing the same issue. How can  I fix it?

Second issue: when I try to open a terminal in Intellij, I'm getting below error
Cannot open Local
Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /opt/ideaIC/plugins/terminal/shell-integrations/bash/bash-integration.bash, -i] in /home/pi/IdeaProjects/grpc-java-course, [columns=260, rows=14], envs={PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-arm64/bin/:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games, XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority, XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg, GDMSESSION=LXDE-pi-labwc, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus, WLR_XWAYLAND=/usr/bin/xwayland-xauth, LABWC_PID=939, INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE=/home/pi/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.3/terminal/history/grpc-java-course-history1, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=labwc:wlroots, SSH_AGENT_PID=1034, LOGNAME=pi, PWD=/opt/ideaIC/bin, XKB_DEFAULT_OPTIONS=, _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1, XCURSOR_THEME=PiXflat, LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8, WLR_DRM_NO_SCANOUT_BG=1, XKB_DEFAULT_MODEL=pc105, SHELL=/bin/bash, LABWC_FALLBACK_OUTPUT=NOOP-1, TERM_SESSION_ID=e979f300-2b7c-47a1-a34d-1d491d0a6a1e, LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8, XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0, SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3, TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM, XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=LXDE-pi-labwc, SHLVL=0, JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-arm64, TERM=xterm-256color, LANG=en_US.UTF-8, XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0, XDG_SESSION_ID=1, XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland, DISPLAY=:0, XKB_DEFAULT_VARIANT=, WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0, XKB_DEFAULT_LAYOUT=us, XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user, _=/opt/ideaIC/bin/idea.sh, XCURSOR_SIZE=24, XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm/data/pi, GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1, DESKTOP_SESSION=LXDE-pi-labwc, USER=pi, DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=57873c29cde38c2d53ea6f8f85ccabc2, XDG_MENU_PREFIX=lxde-pi-, TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXwMu0tc/agent.939, XDG_SEAT=seat0, QT_WAYLAND_DISABLE_WINDOWDECORATION=1, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct, NO_AT_BRIDGE=1, XDG_VTNR=7, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000, HOME=/home/pi}
See IDE log (Help | Show Log in File Manager) for the details.
